# Hibernate Many-to-Many Mapping with seperate dto class

Tags: hibernate-mapping

can any one tell how to get hibernate Many-To-Many mapping with different dto files means suppose there are student and teacher relationship in that i want -
1) Student Dto class
2) Teacher Dto class
3) Student_Teacher Dto class and in this class all mapping are there 
is this possible and how to do it ??

Comment: If you're using an association class, I.e. you student_teacher class, you don't need a many-to-many, you can use two one-to-many mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate collection attribute with @ManyToMany annotation on each of the entities. In your case you will want to annotate Student and Teacher entity. Student_Teacher table will be created automatically if you are using schema export or you can use @JoinTable to specify join table details. This join table will have all the mappings.

For more details I have tried to explain [@ManyToMany mapping](http://blog.techdynamic.me/jpa-mappings-many-to-many-mapping/) here in simple way.